# How do you determine the smallest possible perimeter in a whole number not expression after factoring area?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, area, integers

The **area** of a **square** garden, in square meters, is represented by the expression **169 - 182x + 49x<sup>2</sup>**  What is the smallest possible perimeter of the garder if x is a positive integer?

I factored **169 - 182x + 49x<sup>2</sup>** to be **(7x-13)<sup>2</sup>** so the perimeter would be be 28x-52.  But the answer to the perimeter is 24m with no variable.

**How does the process to this answer work?**

Comment: the perimeter would be $|28x - 104|$ (4 times the side of the square).

Comment: Note that you minimize the perimeter by minimizing the area.

Comment: "*I factored $169-182x+49x^2$ to be $7x-13$*" you seem to mean factored to be $(7x-13)^{\color{red}{2}}$, and so the sidelength of the square is $|7x-13|$.  When the side-length is minimized so too is the perimeter.  Since we are constraining $x$ to be an integer, which of the following is smallest?  $|7\cdot 0 - 13|, |7\cdot 1-13|, |7\cdot 2-13|, |7\cdot 3-13|$.  Can you successfully argue why the smallest side-length must be one of these?  Can you reason then what the smallest perimeter is?  (the answer is *not* $24$)

Answer (score -1):

See that since $x$ is positive then the minimal value for the perimeter (an increasing function) is obtained by taking $x=0$.

Comment: Notice that the area when $x=0$ is $169$ is strictly larger than the area when $x=1$ which is $36$.  A square with a larger area also has a larger perimeter.  Taking $x=0$ does not in this case provide the minimum.

Comment: Yeah misread the question. Tried to delete answer but app won't let me.